# KML Path Not Elevated, Not Continuous, and Continues after end point:

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm plotting the track of something with LON/LAT/ALT values in a text file, but when I import the file to Google Earth, not only is the path not elevated (there are points in the file which are elevated), the line is not continuous, and points appear all over the globe as if the line continues from its end point, which I do not want.

Could anyone tell me any issues they see with my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Style id="yellowLine">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7f00ffff</color>
                <width>4</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark> 
            <name>NAME1</name>
            <description>DESCRIPTION1</description> 
            <Point>
                <coordinates>
                    110.433151670242,    0,  1.64E+04
                </coordinates>
                <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            </Point>

        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#yellowLine</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <extrude>false</extrude>
                <tessellate>false</tessellate>
                <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>
                    0,    0,    1.00E-01
                    ...
                    21.973572010082,    0,  1.18E+06
                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the formatting.

Formatting must be of the form: #,#,# with no exception, so that the code would look like:

```
<coordinates>
num,num,num
...
num,num,num
<coordinates>
```

or

```
<coordinates> num,num,num num,num,num ... num,num,num<coordinates>
```